# Determining if an event target is the child of another element

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to figure out the best way to determine to which parent node an event target belongs.

You have a custom polymer element with 2 or more forms in it. Each form has a submit button:

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form1" method="post" action="/action1">
    <paper-button on-tap="_submitHandler">Send<paper-button>
</form>
<form is="iron-form" id="form2" method="post" action="/action2">
    <paper-button on-tap="_submitHandler">Send<paper-button>
</form>
...
<form is="iron-form" id="formN" method="post" action="/action3">
    <paper-button on-tap="_submitHandler">Send<paper-button>
</form>
```

Then in the  tag you have the handler:

```
_submitHandler: function(e) {
    var path = Polymer.dom(e).path;
    var item = null;
    var form = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        item = path[i];
        switch (item) {
            case this.$.form1:
                form = this.$.form1;
                break;
            case this.$.form2:
                form = this.$.form2;
                break;
            // ... N cases
        }
    }
    if (form != null) {
        form.submit()
    }
}
```

There must be a better way to do this... What would be the right way to handle such a case?

I'm using Polymer 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_submitHandler: function(e) {
    var form = var form = Polymer.dom(e).parentNode;

    if (form != null) {
        form.submit()
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
_submitHandler: function(e) {
    var form = var form = Polymer.dom(e.target).parentNode;

    if (form != null) {
        form.submit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried that. "form" is undefined. BTW i'm using Polymer 1.0

Comment: See my own answer above. Just tested and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is as follows:

```
_submitHandler: function(e) {
    Polymer.dom(e).localTarget.parentNode.submit();
}
```